# Autorun al conectar un usb a un equipo

Tags: windows, script, cmd, windows10, powershell

Estoy intentando que al conectar un USB a un equipo, en este caso usando Windows 10, se auto ejecute un programa o script automáticamente sin tener que ir y ejecutarlo.

He creado un archivo llamado `autorun.inf` en el USB que tiene el siguiente contenido:

```
[autorun]
;Open=Anydesk.exe
ShellExecute=Anydesk.exe
UseAutoPlay=1
```

Con el cual pretendo que al conectar el USB al equipo, se ejecuta el `.exe` de anydesk, el cual se encuentra en la misma ruta dentro del USB que el archivo `.inf`

El problema es que no se ejecuta al conectarlo. ¿Alguien sabe cual es el fallo o en su defecto, la forma correcta de realizar lo que pretendo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si esta en la misma ruta y tiene el mismo nombre?

Comment: Probaste con [autorun]
                    open=Anydesk.exe sin agregar las otras lineas?

Comment: Creo que fue a partir de windows 7 creo recordar, que por seguridad en los propios sistemas operativos, microsoft eliminó esta posibilidad. En sistemas anteriores ese script si funcionaría, pero después de windows 7 ya no. La única opción que yo sepa, sería instalar un programa que monitoree las unidades flash del sistema tipo  "APO USB Autorun". Pero antes de intrucir el USB deberías de haber instalado el programa citado. Un saludo